# Copy-paste through RDP, file size limitation?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, copy-paste

Is there a limitation how large files you can copy paste via RDP (Remote Desktop) in Windows? Is it possible to copy-paste e.g 4 GB files through RDP?

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/q/1797736/964771

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Microsoft, copying files via Remote Desktop Services or Terminal Services with sizes in excess of **2GB** is not supported:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2258090

Comment: but, WHY? this is killin me

Comment: yes indeed why. i need to copy a customer database for testing and its HUGE.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like 7-zip to make a split archive, say 4 x 1GB files, then these can be copied across individually and the original file extracted at the other end.

Answer (score 0):

Today I found out that the limit had been removed between Windows 10 (21H2) and Windows Server 2019 (1809):
I could copy a file with size 4.7GB from Windows 10 to the server using RDP.
However copying a similar file from the same host to Windows Server 2016 (1607) still failed with "Unknown error".