# Ways around copy/paste size limitation for Windows server without sharing

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, file-sharing, copy-paste

I'm trying to allow for users to copy/paste or Click and drag items into a sub folder of a shared parent. The architecture goes along the lines of Parent>Child>Child. The bottom child is not shared, but we want to reduce clutter in the shared folders view for users. Is there any way around this?

PS, I would have asked about this in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/561094/copy-paste-through-rdp-file-size-limitation?newreg=8c81ecaf0f3444dbbb9858f9278b9e79) post, but I'm too new of a user to make comments.

Please let me know if you have any ideas.