# "Unspecified error" when copying file via Remote Desktop Protocol

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, file-transfer

A have a file with size 4.638.646.348 bytes (4.31 GB).
When I try to copy it from Windows Server 2016 (1607) to Windows Server 2019 (1809), I get an "Unspecified errror" as soon as I use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on the target machine (before I had used <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on the source machine).

Both machines are accessed via RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol) from Windows 10 21H2.
In the past I had copied smaller files using those machines without a problem.

Suspecting the file size exceeding 4GB (the 32-bit limit), I tried to transfer a smaller file with size 2.513.850.695 bytes (2.34GB).

Then the copy started, and when the progress bar had reached around 90%, I also got an "Unspecified error".
I suspect it might be caused by the file size exceeding 2GB (the 31-bit (signed 32-bit) limit).

Obvious questions:

1. Is it true that you cannot copy files exceeding 2GB using the Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP), even when all systems involved run a current 64-bit Windows?
2. If so, why does a file transfer exceeding 4GB fail immediately, while a file transfer exceeding 2GB (but not 4GB) starts first, and then seemingly aborts once 2GB of data were transferred?
3. If large file copies are not possible, why isn't there any better error message than "Unspecified error" (it seems the programmer had no idea what's going on either).

Final remark: It seems Microsoft is putting much more effort in making money from existing software rather than providing state-of-the-art software.

Comment: Reasons to request re-opening: The similar question's answer is more than 10 years old, so the software at that time was much older, and maybe (question and answer lack the details) it was not 64-bit. Also, AFAIK, the RDP protocol was revised multiple times.

Comment: Even the [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-DE/troubleshoot/windows-server/remote/copying-2-gb-file-by-clipboard-redirection-fails) has not a solution for all cases, e.g.: Copying a file from one RDP session to another RDP session without making a temporary copy at the local host. Also it claims there would be no error message. -- So even when closing this as duplicate, the other question would need an answer that is covers all cases.

Comment: It would be interesting to find an answer that is based on the actual protocol "on wire" rather than an implementation. However it seems the actual protocol is "company confidential".

Comment: Does copying a smaller file using the same protocol work? If so, the duplicate stands. The protocol is closed source and we cannot answer why questions. Saying it has changed does not mean that the file size limitation is something that has changed. You will need to test the marked duplicate answer before it will be clear whether this needs to be reopened.

Comment: @music2myear "*The protocol is closed source and we cannot answer why questions*" is wrong: With closed source not *everybody* can answer, but *someone*. So while there is hope for an answer, it's a valid question IMHO.

Comment: Yes, somebody can answer, but the Microsoft employees who would know this don't work here. We're just regular volunteer Randoms from the internet. Also, it is HIGHLY unlikely a super Corp would disclose internal details of a closed source tool to satisfy the curiousity of an internet random. This site isn't Microsoft support.

Comment: @music2myear The site may not be Microsoft support, but if it's also not Windows support, what's the use of all those questions then? Still the answer could be: "*Yes, you are correct, the maximum transfer size even on a 64 bit Windows is 2GB (2^31). Still systems may behave quite differently when that size is exceeded; one of the reactions could be "Unspecified error".*"

Comment: 1/2 There's a difference between having factual information about undocumented features of a closed source product, and being able to determine some factual answer based on observation. Your question could be restated, refocused, and reopened. You have asked 3 questions; this site strongly recommends one question per post in order to get one good answer to that question. One of those questions you ask is clearly something only an internal MS dev working on this system would be able to answer, so that is an easy fix.

Comment: 2/2 Your question has multiple reasons why it is closed: Dup is just the more helpful to you by pointing towards a place at least one of your questions was answered.